# How to find a real orthogonal matrix of determinant $1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

> A real orthogonal matrix $A$ is proper if $\det A=1     $.
>
> Find $2\times 2$ proper matrix $A$

I tried to use the fact that product of $A$ and its transpose is equal to identity.

But, there were bunch of equations which seem not related to each other and can not find such $A$.

Comment: Example: $2\times 2$ identity.

Answer (score 2):

For any $\theta$, 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & \sin\theta\\
-\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is such a matrix. Actually, they all have this form.

Comment: Can u swap sin and cos?

Comment: try for instance to substract $\pi / 2$ to $\theta$.